Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully
i was trying to install pyaudio for an AI project but when i type `pip install pyaudio', i got this
C:\Users\Admin>pip install pyaudio
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.14.tar.gz (47 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      WARNING:root:Warning: VCPKG_PATH envrionment variable not set.
      INFO:root:running bdist_wheel
      INFO:root:running build
      INFO:root:running build_py
      INFO:root:creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyaudio
      INFO:root:copying src\pyaudio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\pyaudio
      INFO:root:running build_ext
      INFO:root:building 'pyaudio._portaudio' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pyaudio)

please help me it's very important for me
i tried everything i could but it still didn't work.

i'm using Windows 10 btw

Duplicate of How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required" when installing Python packages?

For the latest version 0.2.14 there are wheels for Pythons up to 3.12 but not 3.13. Downgrade your Python, use 3.12.
Or compile from sources. Or install conda and install PyAudio using conda.
